# Textbooks or lecture notes about mean field games

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, oc.optimization-and-control, stochastic-differential-equations, optimal-transportation, differential-game-theory

I am looking for a good introductory level textbook (or lecture notes) on mean field games that would be suitable for a graduate course. Ideally, it would include some brief words about optimal control and dynamic programming. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The [lecture notes](http://www.science.unitn.it/~bagagiol/NotesByCardaliaguet.pdf) on mean-field games of [Lions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierre-Louis_Lions), from a course at the Collège de France, have been typed out by Pierre Cardaliaguet. They address both optimal control and dynamic programming. I would think it will be hard to beat these for an authoritative exposition. For a summary of open problems you could look [here.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11537-007-0657-8)

Comment: Thank you Carlo.

Comment: The second link is dead. The file can be found here: https://basepub.dauphine.psl.eu/handle/123456789/2263 or https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11537-007-0657-8 In the future you may find it searching for "mean field games survey  by Lasry and Lions"

Comment: @plm --- thank you, I have fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's my go to links:

1. PDE flavor notes by Ryzhik: [https://math.stanford.edu/~ryzhik/STANFORD/MEAN-FIELD-GAMES/notes-mean-field.pdf](https://math.stanford.edu/%7Eryzhik/STANFORD/MEAN-FIELD-GAMES/notes-mean-field.pdf)
2. Probability flavor notes by Lacker:
   [http://www.columbia.edu/~dl3133/MFGSpring2018.pdf](http://www.columbia.edu/%7Edl3133/MFGSpring2018.pdf)
3. Background material on mean-field interacting processes by Golse:
   https://arxiv.org/abs/1301.5494

Books:

1). There is a two volume textbook "Probabilistic Theory of Mean Field Games with Applications " by Carmona and Delarue

2). A very comprehensive textbook on MFG is being written by Tamer Basar, but I don't know if it is ready yet.

Comment: Thank you Piyush!